# How to implement a dictionary in android

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I want to implement a dictionary in android using the following method :

```
private final Dictionary<String,String> allWords = new Dictionary<String, String>() {
```

However, whenever I try to add it I get this whole mess below it, and when I tried using it , I keep getting an error.
I know I'm supposed to implement the functions in the abstract class but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do it than to code it manually.

```
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> keys() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> elements() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String get(Object key) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String put(String key, String value) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String remove(Object key) {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Update the code with error that you are facing

Comment: not sure if this question needs the android or android studio tag at all, might just be a java question

Comment: Please look over here https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-create-a-dictionary-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I just used

```
private final HashMap<String,String> allWords = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is already a built-in class called [Dictionary](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Dictionary) in Java. Therefore the IDE ask you to override the member functions. If you want to implement everything from scratch, use another class name. Don't use `Dictionary`. E.g. name your calss `MyDictionary`, `CustomDictionary`, or something like that. Avoid built-in class names.